# Firebase sub-child removed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to get if subchild removed. 
db structure is:

```
users:{
  a: {
    friends: {
      b:Jhon,
      c:Ted
  },
  b: { 
    friends: {
      a: Tom
    }
  },
  c: {
    friends:{
      a: Tom
    }
  }
}
```

I want get event while anybody removes any child from friends. 
Attaching event to every user is not a good way. 

I am trying in node.js admin

Comment: how about attaching a `child_changed` event? that event will be triggered every time each child (or user) 's data is changed/updated.

Comment: @Wilik in your way i must keep all data in a variable and in every change get what changed. 
I thing it is not efficient

Comment: well, then the only way is only by attaching `child_removed` event at every `userid/friends`, your code is on a server anyway

Comment: For 10K users it is 10K listeners :(

Comment: can you tell me why do you want to get "friend removed" event?

Comment: when a removes b from friend, it must be removed from b to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way, you can create a special node for "friend removal request", so the client only writes to this node, then the server handles the deletion.

First, look at this database structure

```
{
    users: {
        a: {
            friends: {
                b:Jhon,
                c:Ted
            },
        }
        b: { 
            friends: {
                a: Tom
            }
        },
        c: {
            friends:{
                a: Tom
            }
        }
    }
    friend_removal_request : {
        <push_id>: {
            first_user: a,
            second_user: b
        }
    }
}
```

- The server attach `child_added` listener to `friend_removal_request`
- If a user wants to delete a friend of their, their client writes a new entry (by using `DatabaseReference.push()` method) to `friend_removal_request`. `first_user` is the user's id, `second_user` is their friend's id
- Then the listener at the server will be fired, the server now can proceed to delete their friendship by setting a `null` value (or call `remove()`) to `/users/$first_user/friends/$second_user` and `/users/$second_user_user/friends/$first_user`
- After the friendship is deleted, the server deletes that request `snapshot.ref.remove()`

Now, the listener is only attached to a node.

This is my idea, let me know if you have another concern with this method.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: awesome, this is also a way to prevent the consistency just in case if the server goes down :)